# Which Firebase service to use to remotely set privacy policy for Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-remote-config

I want to be able to set the privacy policy of my app from the server. I am not sure which service to use. I thought about Firestore and remote config but both of them don't seem to be a good solution. Can you recommend which service to use?

Comment: Right now firestore is most flexible database in my opinion. And it is a best solution to any thing except chat apps but for that you have firebase realtime database.

Comment: You can assign admin role to any user token and setup admin rules in firestore so admin can do any thing. Or if you need to read other users data, delete them, disable them you just need to make firebase functions with firebase-admin SDK and no need to worry about rules you have in firestore or authentication or storage etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Cloud Firestore** is the **most flexible, scalable NoSQL cloud database to store and sync data**. It keeps your data in sync across client apps through realtime listeners and offers offline support so you can build responsive apps that work regardless of network latency or Internet connectivity.

In Firestore, you can take the advantage of **IAM’s security principle of least privilege** and can grant only the necessary access to your resources. For example, you can grant the datastore.indexAdmin role to a user, which allows the user to create, modify, delete, list, or view indexes.

Also with Firestore libs, you get all **the goodies of Firebase suite - auth, serverless, storage, ML, and others** perfectly blended with the language specifics.

Another great advantage of using Firestore is its **Offline capabilities**.

However, have a look at this [privacy policy](https://www.privacypolicies.com/blog/privacy-policy-firebase/) and [privacy settings for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/storing-privacy-settings#storing_privacy_settings) before framing the privacy policy.